# Systemjs config to load templateUrl in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem when using systemjs with angular2.

*index.html*

```
System.config({
     packages: {
       'app': {
               format: 'register',
               defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'rxjs': {
               defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        '*': 'dist/*',
        'app/*': 'dist/app/*',
        'angular2/*': 'node_modules/angular2/*',
        'rxjs/*': 'node_modules/rxjs/*'
    }
});

System.import('app/main.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

*app.js*

```
import {NavbarComponent} from './components/navbar/navbar';
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.html',
    directives: [RouterOutlet, NavbarComponent]
})
```

This is structure:

[image]

When run serve:

```
dev: {
        port: 8080,
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        open: '/',
        root: '.',
        file: "index.html",
        wait: 1000
    },
```

All .js files load with path http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/app/.../....js
But templateUlr load with path http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/.../...js 
How to config to load templateUrl with path as .js file ?

Comment: i think the problem is in your file structure. surely the file structure is not correct that's why path for html not found. post you file structure in question too if possible

Comment: Hi @PardeepJain, I added image for structure, and config to run serve.

Comment: you have to give path from the src folder like `src/app/app.html`

Comment: @PardeepJain can I config to auto map path when load templateUrl? or any solution  I can run serve for dev that don't change code?

Comment: you are talking about `.map` files ? your templateUrl is working now or not ?

Comment: I talking about `System.config({ map: {...}, paths:{...} })`. If I change code to `templateUrl: 'dist/app/app.html'` it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this as answer because as comment this one is too long !!!

Firstly as answer to your question -- you have to give path from the src folder like which is working now after my comment.
Secondly you are talking about `.map` files--

yes you can config to auto map path when load templateUrl you have to make some gulp task as following:

put this code in the gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('compile-ts', function () {
    var sourceTsFiles = [
        config.allTs,
        config.allcompoTs
    ];

    var tsResult = gulp
        .src(sourceTsFiles)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tsOutputPath));
});
```

and this one in your gulp.config.js

```
module.exports = function() {

    var config = {
        allTs : 'src/*.ts',
        allcompoTs: 'src/**/*.ts',
        tsOutputPath : 'dist/',
        index : 'index.html'
    };
    return config;
};
```

now you can config gulp task according to your requirements.
hope it will help you !

Comment: Thanks @Pardeep, I build success. I run my app that load file form `dist`, and serve load `.js` by path `http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/app/app.js` and load `.html` by path `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/app.html` (it wrong). I don't want change `templateUrl` form `app/app.html` to `dist/app/app.html`. Any idea for this issue. This is my app https://github.com/Sophia-nguyen/myApp/tree/master. Could you please help me to check it.

Comment: whats wrong here ? its right to load HTML from from app folder and js from the dist folder is't it ?

Comment: Like this, I write code in `src` folder, then compile to `dist` folder. After that, I config to run server, but If I define server with `root: '.'`, it will load `.html` file with path `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/app.html` >> not found. and If I define server with `root: 'dist/'` >> `node-modules` not found. And I don't know how to run server with content in `dist` :(

Comment: i think you are getting wrong. listen, when you try `.app/app.html` it will try to get path from the dist folder where angular2 does't found correct path of HTML rather you have to specify .html path like this 'src/app/app.html` (correct )insted of './app/app.html' . also we have to load only `.js` files from the dist folder and `.html` files from the src folder. i hope it is clear now for you !!

Comment: and secondly use `System.import('path_of_bootstraped_file_from_dist_folder');` in your index.html. like this i have used `System.import('dist/app');`

Comment: thanks @Pardeep, I'm clear, I will try working with your solution, I think it work. Thanks again.

Comment: It work for me :). And one more question, you know any gulp plugin that build .html files to one file main.min.js for angular2-typeScript-systemjs app. I try using `gulp-templatecache` but angular.module not work.

Comment: no i have no idea about this !!...will you tell me why you want to build main.min.js file from .html file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100644/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-sophia).

Comment: yep, because I will build project and hosting to one server. So I want compile and minify all .html + .js files to one file, then I will load it by System.import('dist/app/main.js') etc. I don't want upload all html files in src folder to server.